# sbt multi-project build dependency

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have a multi-project build in sbt as described in http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html.

ProjectA dependsOn (ProjectB, Common)

ProjectB dependsOn (Common)

**ProjectA** and **ProjectB** can be **run independently** by itself. There are some common resources (logback.xml) shared in both the projects. The problem is, for ProjectA to run, I have to put ProjectB's "target/classes" in the classpath and when I do that, it complains that logback.xml is found multiple times. Is there a solution to this? I don't want to build jar of projectB everytime and use it as libraryDependencies.

Comment: The short answer is that you shouldn't have `logback.xml` on your classpath for a library (for `ProjectB`). You should pass in its location on the commandline when running as an application.

Comment: The issue is, it is there in the resources directory which is automatically copied to "target/classes" by the build.

Comment: Yes. You need to put it somewhere else (`src/main/conf`, for example) and access it at runtime in your preferred way.

Comment: how do you do this `The problem is, for ProjectA to run, I have to put ProjectB's "target/classes" in the classpath and when I do that, it complains that logback.xml is found multiple times.`?